# whenever i run npm start on my react it gives an error. Image below

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOjwN.png)[image of the error message am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOuI.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOuI.png): Tried yarn start getting same error message
  [3]: Tried npm install react-scripts
  [4]: The second image is after i tried cd real_app and trying the link on the error message

Comment: Where is that project located? Probably not in your python directory...

Comment: it looks like you're in the parent directory. `package.json` should be in the current directory when you run that command. Maybe try `cd real_app` first

Comment: At the end of the error log there is a line pointing you to a file to see more details about this error. Have you opened the file? Typically those errors are related to permissions or incorrect directory tree and this file can guide you in the right direction

Comment: have run cd real_app and am getting an error message "cannot find path" and i have tried the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the wrong directory. Looking at you file structure I can see that you are trying to start the app inside of:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Worx\react\app
```

However as the error denotes it cannot find the package.json file. That is because your project path (where package.json is located) is actually:

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Python Worx\react\app\real_app
```

In your terminal there type:

```
cd real_app
```

Then run your npm start.

Comment: when i ran the cd real_app, I got an error "cannot find path"

Comment: Thanks you have been of great help, found out I had multiple react files in that particular folder. Had to delete them all cause,the npm start kept trying to find that particular real_app I created a first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to run `npm start` in the wrong directory. You are running the command in a directory called `/app`, and in the navigator pane to the left it shows that `package.json` is in a directory called `real_app`.

You need to run those npm commands in the root directory of your app, where `package.json` is.

To find the correct directory you can right click `real_app` on the left pane and select `Open in Terminal`, and try to run the npm command from there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks you have been of great help, found out I had multiple react files in that particular folder. Had to delete them all cause,the npm start kept trying to find that particular real_app I created a first.

Answer (score -1):

I had many react files in that particular folder, had to find the real_app and did the npm start there and it worked. Had to delete all other react files that i wasnt working with, guess the npm start was looking for the instance of the first react app I downloaded and that was why I was getting the error message.
Thanks to @Sammy I. and @basic for your help, without you guys would not have gotten this solved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4P2s.png)